# How can i shut off Netsuite Expense Report email that are going to the users upon modification?

Tags: netsuite

I checked email transactions and saved searches. Till now this notification is on going and cannot figure a way to stop it. I appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks. Do u have other recommendations?
This is the subject am having on the template: Expense Report Line Item was modified by the Finance Team

There is always an email that is being sent from NetSuite when we modify expense reports that I cannot seem to shut off? Whenever we modify any expense report the user is getting an email that expense report line was modified. How do i shut this off? Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the email transactions on the transaction records.  Or, update your workflows to control when emails are sent.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a saved search setup to send an email whenever an expense report is modified.  Find the saved search sending the email.  Edit that search and under the "Email" tab, uncheck the "Send email alerts when records are created/updated" box.

[image]